# iOS Dev using XCode5 - Precompile of .pch failing, appears to be building in c context rather than ObjC

Tags: ios, build, xcode5, pch

I have a project for an iOS app that Ive used in the past, the app is on the store.

In attempting a recent update after using the source in Xcode 5 for the first time I find the pch precompile is failing like this:

```
Duplicate protocol definition of 'NSObject' is ignored
Duplicate interface definition for class 'NSObject'
Expected parameter declarator
Expected '(' 
Unexpected '@' in program
'@end' must appear in an Objective-C context .. etc etc..
```

Which looks to me as though it is attempting to compile ObjC source as C.

I've not changed the pch file, it looks like this:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#endif
```

I'm not knowledgable at all about build settings and the like, I've had a look at these and can see nothing obvious, and as far as I recall I haven't changed anything since it last built successfully on Xcode 4.

Any ideas?